# How to install Magento using comand line on local computers

Tags: magento, command-line

How can I install Magento using command-line? 
I tried to install Magento using command-line but I wasn't successful, so I would just like to know if it's possible to use command-line to install Magento on my local PC.

Comment: How did you try to install using command line?

Comment: This is not a programming related question. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. You should try asking this question on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented on [Installing Magento Via SSH](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about "command line". Magento for the most part is a simple drag'n drop by scp/sftp/ftp if you expand the archive on the remote workstation.

Of course you could also just stuff the install archive on the web server document root via scp/sftp/ftp and then issue tar -xzf/gunzip/unzip and expand the archive there to expand out the Magento application directory/file structure.

Either way, for manual install, it's just an archive that's dearchived by the usual standard means.

On your local "PC", you will probably be using 7-zip if it's Windows based.

Of course this all depends on something *really basic*, **have you set up a fully functional server running Apache, MySQL and PHP for this???** and what OS is this "PC" running?